# Почему не срабатывает машина состояний aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

При вводе в чат тг слова: /изменения, должна запуститься машина состояния. Но ничего не происходит!
Код разбит по модулям, ничего не напутано, код запускается без ошибок, но вот машина состояния не запускается(

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from create_bot import dp, bot
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from data_base import botbd
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

#появляется после ввода /start
button_menu = KeyboardButton("Меню")
greet_kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True).add(button_menu)
 
#появляется после ввода слова Меню
button_wr = KeyboardButton("/изменения")
button_stats = KeyboardButton("stats")
button_other = KeyboardButton("other")
button_info = KeyboardButton("info")
greet_menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(button_wr, button_stats, button_other, button_info)
 
#при вводе /start
#@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Привет, для продолжения перейдите в меню!", reply_markup=greet_kb)
 
#@dp.message_handler()
async def menu_command(message : types.Message):
    if message.text == 'меню' or message.text == 'Меню':
        await message.answer("Сделайте свой выбор!", reply_markup=greet_menu)
 
 
################################################################
 
class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    winers = State()
    losers = State()
 
#тут машина состояния должна начать работать, после выбора на клавиатуре кнопки /изменения
#@dp.message_handler(commands='изменения', state=None)
async def cm_start(message : types.Message):
    await FSMAdmin.winers.set()
    await message.reply('Введите количество побед:')
 
#@dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.winers)
async def load_win(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['winers'] = message.text
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await message.reply('Введите количество поражений:')
 
#@dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.losers)
async def load_lose(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['losers'] = message.text
 
    await botbd.sql_add_command(state)
    await state.finish()
 
 
 
 
 
def register_handlers_client(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(process_start_command, commands=['start'])
    dp.register_message_handler(menu_command)
    dp.register_message_handler(cm_start, commands='изменения', state=None) 
    dp.register_message_handler(load_win, state=FSMAdmin.winers)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_lose, state=FSMAdmin.losers)
```

это в основном файле, который запускается:

```
from aiogram.utils import executor
from create_bot import dp
from handlers import client, other
from data_base import botbd

client.register_handlers_client(dp)
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Это в файле с dp:

```
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from config import TOKEN
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
 
storage = MemoryStorage()
 
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай так

```
#@dp.message_handler(text=['меню', 'Меню'])
async def menu_command(message : types.Message):
    await message.answer("Сделайте свой выбор!", reply_markup=greet_menu)

def register_handlers_client(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(process_start_command, commands=['start'])
    dp.register_message_handler(menu_command, text=['меню', 'Меню'])
    dp.register_message_handler(cm_start, commands='изменения', state=None) 
    dp.register_message_handler(load_win, state=FSMAdmin.winers)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_lose, state=FSMAdmin.losers)
```

Answer (score 0):

только что столкнулся с похожей проблемой. Признаюсь честно, код я весь не смотрел, но, если я правильно понял суть вопроса - команда пишется в чате, в котором несколько людей, а не напрямую боту. Так вот вся соль в том, что для того, чтобы состояния работали в чатах, то есть не напрямую боту, ему нужно в этом чате выдать права администратора. Не знаю почему и как это работает именно так, но иначе работать отказывается